# reliability solution for resend a packet in network

Tags: network-protocols, packet-sniffers

actually i want to record the data that outgoing at my network
then resend them
for example in yahoo A person send a message to B person
then A person record the data with X program and close the yahoo 
at the end the A person send the data has been recorded by X program and B person receives exactly the data received before
is it possible? or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it is not possible because there is many concept in any data transfer to server. 
one of that is freshness that mean we use some data like date for check a message and if this data is duplicate, then the pm block. 
and many mechanism for blocking duplicate message

Answer (score 0):

It seems what You're looking for is a combination of `tcpdump` and `tcpreplay`.

`tcpdump` can record any network traffic on the interface, while `tcpreplay` can resend all of the packets from a certain tcpdump file.

If You're programming something, then I'm not entirely sure though if You really wish to play with this sort of thing on packet/network level. Just saving the payload in Your own application and sending it back whenever feels comfortable seems simpler, but then You'd lose the 'sending exactly the same packets' idea.

Comment: tanks doubleud, its good idea for starting, but if som app use ACK method for sync this method able to do my story?